# Do we have ROM in Von Neuman Architecture?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

According to Von Neumann architecture ,we have a single Program and Data Memory which is called RAM ,and ROM is a program Memory in case of harvard architecture so do we have ROM in Von Neumann architecture or is it the case that BIOS is present in ROM , so ROM will always be present in all kinds of architecture ?

Comment: You make so many wrong assumptions that I don't know where I should start explaining. ROM is a kind of memory that can't be written to. RAM is a kind of memory that can be read non-sequentially. So ROM can be RAM. BIOS is present in PCs *only* (not mobiles, embedded computers etc.) and is already being replaced by UEFI, it has nothing to do with theoretical computer architectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the basic [Von Neumann Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture) the ROM would be somewhere in your Memory, yes. But as it's a theoretical Architecture you can't map it 1:1 to the real world. It's only really saying that there is some form of memory that data can be read and possibly written to. If that is RAM, a ROM, an HDD or so something else would be a different story.

At [the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Mitigations) of the Wiki article you will also find that even something like the number of caches etc. is already not part of the model.

Comment: So that means we can have a hierarchy of memory , and at every hierarchical level , we will have both Program and data stored in it , and we even can have ROM at some level , is this terminology correct

Comment: Yes. In that architecture there is no distinction what is stored in the memory (in comparison to the [Harvard Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture)). The definition just says there is storage and it can be used. What is actually done to "implement" it is a different story.